# Why is width of page larger than screen width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need help finding out what is causing the extra width on my website.
USERNAME: stack PASSWORD: password
the link is http://josesebastianmanunta.com/erp/
if you look at the bottom bar which has the open button floated to the right you will see that when the screen loads about half of the button is not visible...the button is floated to the right and the  its in has an absolute positioning `bottom:0; left:0; width:100%;`

In a few words: what is causing the page to be bigger than the width of the screen?

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SCREAMING!

Comment: Stop shouting. Might get an answer

Comment: Please look on Stackoverflow home page. How many other post titles do you see in all caps??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that in the W3C box model, the width is the **content** width, and is separate from the contribution of the padding and border.

You can add the following to your CSS:

```
body { box-sizing: border-box; }
body *, body *:before, body *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }
```

That'll make the default calculation for `width` take into account padding and border. When that's added to your page, the horizontal scrollbar goes away.

Comment: awesome ...it worked but now i have to adjust some other sections...haha....THANKS for the answer and explanation.

Comment: @smanunta well overall it's *much* easier to work in the "border-box" mode. Good luck!